# What happened to the wives of Pandavas except Draupadi in the end of Mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata, pandavas

Pandavas and Draupadi except Yudhisthira fall during their journey but in the end, what happened to the wives of other Pandavas?

Comment: Draupadi was a common permanent wife. Some individual wives were only temporary.